# Open a new Angular tab with object data?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am using Angular 7 and I would like to open a new Angular tab with object data.
When the user clicks on the button, the object data will be sent and open a new tab with the data.

I have tried 3 things for that.

1. I used 'window.open()'. I could open a new tab easily but I couldn't send big data like an object data.

> let win = window.open('test-child', '_blank');
>
> win.document.getElementById('text1');

2. I also used Router. However it couldn't open a new tab. Just navigate to the url.

> this.router.navigate(['test', obj]);

3. I used the data service. I made data service and there are setValue and getValue. However, the child component couldn't get the data.

ex) data.service.ts

```
private _data = {};

setValue(value) { this._data = value; }

getValue() { return this._data;}
```

test.ts

```
obj = { name: 'pat', age: 30 };

openNewTab() { 
    this.data.setOption(this.obj); 
    windows.open('test-child', '_blank');
}
```

test-child.ts

```
data: any;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() { this.data = this.dataService.getValue(); }
```

So in this case, how can I send object data to open a new component tab in Angular? Please anyone help me.

Comment: Try to use "virtual tabs". Meaning tabs that are inside your app

Comment: By "Angular tab" you mean a new browser tab running your Angular app ? Does the data have to come from the original tab? You could point the new tab to a specific URL that retrieves the data from the server or the browser's local storage.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging You can use document messaging. This is not angular related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share the data between multiple tabs by using `localStorage`.

The data stored in localStorage persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

You can set item in localStorage as below before window.open()

```
let data = {name : 'test' };
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify(data));
```

and when new tab is opened you can get the data object by using

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
```

**Note:** Do not save sensitive data in localStorage.

It works on same-origin policy. So, data stored will only be available on the same origin.